# The controller with the name 'TabsDemoCtrl' is not registered

Tags: html, css, angularjs, thymeleaf

```html
                <div ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo" ng-controller="TabsDemoCtrl">
                    <uib-tabset active="active"> <uib-tab index="0"
                        heading="Static title">Static content</uib-tab> <uib-tab
                        index="$index + 1" ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}"
                        disable="tab.disabled"> {{tab.content}} </uib-tab> <uib-tab
                        index="3" select="alertMe()"> <uib-tab-heading>
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></i> Alert! </uib-tab-heading> I've got an HTML
                    heading, and a select callback. Pretty cool! </uib-tab> </uib-tabset>
                </div>
```

```
<script
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/ng/tweet/app.js}"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">



<script>
 angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);
 angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('TabsDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $window) {
   $scope.tabs = [
     { title:'Dynamic Title 1', content:'Dynamic content 1' },
     { title:'Dynamic Title 2', content:'Dynamic content 2', disabled: true }
   ];

   $scope.alertMe = function() {
     setTimeout(function() {
       $window.alert('You\'ve selected the alert tab!');
     });
   };
   $scope.model = {
     name: 'Tabs'
   };
 });
  </script>
```

it never works. I can't figure out the cause of the error. what could it be from. Error is "The controller with the name 'TabsDemoCtrl' is not registered."

Comment: I threw all this in a snippet and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

I altered some of your code and this (below) is now working for me.

Note that I included everything in one file.

It's possible that the reason it isn't working in your environment is that you're using two files..

(1) .html file

(2) .js file for your controller.

If this is the case (two files), you'll want to link these files by creating a connection to your controller at the bottom of your.html file, like this:

```
   <script src="tabs-demo-controller.js"></script>
```

Here's my code (in one file)..

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html ng-app="myApp">
        <head>
            <title>Angular Test Project</title>
            <meta charset="utf-8"/>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.11/angular.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/ng/tweet/app.js}"></script>
            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
            <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
            <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"><link>
        </head>

        <body>
            <div ng-controller="TabsDemoCtrl">
                <uib-tabset active="active"> 
                    <uib-tab index="0" heading="Static title">Static content</uib-tab>                
                    <uib-tab 
                        index="$index + 1" 
                        ng-repeat="tab in tabs" 
                        heading="{{tab.title}}"
                        disable="tab.disabled"> {{tab.content}}             
                    </uib-tab>
                    <uib-tab index="3" select="alertMe()">  I've got an HTML heading, and a select callback. Pretty cool! </uib-tab>                    
                    <uib-tab-heading><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></i> Alert! </uib-tab-heading>               
                </uib-tabset>
            </div>
        </body>

        <script>
            angular.module('myApp', [ui.bootstrap]).
                controller('TabsDemoCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) { 
                    $scope.tabs = [
                        { title:'Dynamic Title 1', content:'Dynamic content 1' },
                        { title:'Dynamic Title 2', content:'Dynamic content 2', disabled: true }
                    ];                        
                    $scope.alertMe = function() {
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            $window.alert('You\'ve selected the alert tab!');
                        });
                    };
                    $scope.model = {
                        name: 'Tabs'
                    };
            }]);
        </script>
    </html>
```